# LetsEncrypt Certificate is updated, but still showing old date on the website (restarted Apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, lets-encrypt

Running Apache on EC2 ubuntu server, using letsencrypt certificate, which I see if I run `sudo certbot certificates`. I manually renewed it and confirmed the dates on the server, but the certificate on the website is still showing the old date.

Then I restarted the server with `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`, but still don't see any changes on my site's certificate date. Please help, expiring in a couple of days..

Comment: How did you manually renew it?

Comment: *What* dates you confirmed? How SSL in the Apache is configured (what are `SSLCertificateFile`, `SSLCertificateKeyFile`)? Let's Encrypt certificates lie in `/etc/letsencrypt/archive/<cn>/{cert,privkey,chain,fullchain}N.pem`, and there are symlinks to latest cert in the `/etc/letsencrypt/live/<cn>/`. So your Apache must be configured to use these symlinks in ../live/ directly, or those latest files must be copied somewhere after each renew where Apache finds them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find where SSLCertificateKeyFile path is located. When I run  cerbot certificates, it shows 2 .pem files under /live/ directory with renewed dates. But I guess my Apache is not finding those files